# Symfony2 - Get external content when rendering template

Tags: html, templates, symfony

Beginner in Symfony2, so maybe it's a dumb question.

I would need to get the response of an HTTP query (external server) and put it on a template before sending it to the client.

Like

```
<div id="main_content">
  Lorem Ipsum
  <div id="external_content">
    {% get_content_by_url 'http://external.com/uri' params_object %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Or maybe I should get the response from the controller and pass it as a variable to the template ?

What is the best practice (or am I on a totaly wrong way :) ?

Comment: Hi,

there are different ways to do:

1. Get the content in the controller and render it in twig
2. Let twig call an extra controller which handles the data
3. include the data with jQuery (ajax)

Comment: 1 and 2 seem better for security

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [this bundle](http://knpbundles.com/sonata-project/SonataGoutteBundle)

after enters this code in your controller:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://symfony-reloaded.org/');
$response = $client->getResponse();
$content = $response->getContent();
```

and finaly in file twig :

```
<div id="main_content">
    Lorem Ipsum
<div id="external_content">
    {{ content  }}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems simple. Can we do a POST request with parameters with the same method ?

Comment: yes : '$crawler = $client->request('POST', 'http://www.symfony-project.org/',params request); '